# Can't modify frozen Fixnum on Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I have the following code:

```
require 'prime'
class Numeric
  #... math helpers

  def divisors
    return [self] if self == 1
    @divisors ||= prime_division.map do |n,p|
      (0..p).map { |i| n**i }
    end.inject([1]) do |a,f|
      a.product(f)
    end.map { |f| f.flatten.reduce(:*) } - [self]
  end

  def divisors_sum
     @divisors_sum ||= divisors.reduce(:+)
  end

   #... more methods that evaluate code and 'caches' and assigns (||=) to instance variables
end
```

Which outputs an error with:

```
> 4.divisors
/home/cygnus/Projects/project-euler/stuff/numbers.rb:24:in `divisors_sum': can't modify frozen Fixnum (RuntimeError)
```

The error disappears when I remove caching into the instance variables `@divisors`, `@divisors_sum`... etc. And this only happens on ruby 2.0. Ran it on 1.9.3 without issues. What's happening?

Comment: Confirmed code works ok on 1.9.3 Also confirmed not working in 2.0.0 for me. Adding an instance variable to a Fixnum is quite unusual though.

Comment: Tried to speed up procces. Some methods could take a couple of seconds, and calculating it all again over and over for a large set of numbers makes execution time go up.

Comment: `prime` is gem? which statement is on line#24?

Comment: I think the frozen fixnums are here to stay, from comments like this in ruby-core: http://www.atdot.net/sp/view/4qjkcm/readonly so I'd suggest simply caching the data outside of Fixnum.

Comment: This is really odd, I'm not trying to modify the Fixnum instance itself(which obviously can't be done), but the variable that holds it.

Comment: Ǹo sane person would try to `1 = 3`. But I would say *!n* can be 'rubyzed' as `n.factorial`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@divisors` is an instance variable on an instance of Fixnum, so you are trying to alter it. You probably shouldn't be doing this.

What about this?

```
module Divisors
  def self.for(number)
    @divisors ||= { }
    @divisors[number] ||= begin
      case (number)
      when 1
        [ number ]
      else
        prime_division.map do |n,p|
          (0..p).map { |i| n**i }
        end.inject([1]) do |a,f|
          a.product(f)
        end.map { |f| f.flatten.reduce(:*) } - [ number ]
      end
    end
  end

  def self.sum(number)
     @divisors_sum ||= { }
     @divisors_sum[number] ||= divisors(number).reduce(:+)
  end
end

class Numeric
  #... math helpers

  def divisors
    Divisors.for(self)
  end

  def divisors_sum
     Divisors.sum(self)
  end
end
```

This means that the methods in Numeric do not modify any instance, the cache is stored elsewhere.

Comment: [Another approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15842123/1074296) can keep the logic in the class being extended and move the instance data into an external module.

Comment: That approach has the side-effect of creating more instance methods. When modifying core classes, it's always best to keep your footprint as small as possible.

Comment: I agree it's important to keep the footprint light, especially if you're writing library code. Both your approach and mine define `divisors` and `divisors_sum` within `Numeric`.  The only additional method is the mixedin `fcache`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @tadman's answer, the reason why works in `1.9.3` and not in `2.0.0` is because 2 years ago the decision was made to freeze the Fixnums (and Bignums) as evidenced by [this](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/52584) and [this](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3222).

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out ruby core has decided Fixnums and Bignums are now frozen, so you can't set an instance variable within objects of those classes.

A work around is to make an external module which keeps a cache of hashes indexed by the value of these frozen objects and use elements of these hashes instead of instance vars:

```
require 'prime'

module FrozenCacher
  def FrozenCacher.fcache
    @frozen_cache ||= {}
  end

  def fcache
    FrozenCacher.fcache[self] ||= {}
  end
end

class Numeric
  include FrozenCacher
  #... math helpers

  def divisors
    return [self] if self == 1
    fcache[:divisors] ||= prime_division.map do |n,p|
      (0..p).map { |i| n**i }
    end.inject([1]) do |a,f|
      a.product(f)
    end.map { |f| f.flatten.reduce(:*) } - [self]
  end

  def divisors_sum
    fcache[:divisors_sum] ||= divisors.reduce(:+)
  end

   #... more methods that evaluate code and 'caches' and assigns (||=) to instance variables
end

puts 4.divisors.inspect           # => [1, 2]
puts FrozenCacher.fcache.inspect  # => {4=>{:divisors=>[1, 2]}}
puts 10.divisors.inspect          # => [1, 5, 2]
puts FrozenCacher.fcache.inspect  # => {4=>{:divisors=>[1, 2]}, 10=>{:divisors=>[1, 5, 2]}}
```

Comment: Not bad, I like the idea of keeping the logic within `Numeric`.

Comment: Clever solution. I would be concerned about garbage collection though. I think the circular dependency means the int will never be GC'd (and nor will the item from the cache).

Comment: @mahemoff It's the nature of simple caches to always grow. If this is a concern, substitute an LRU or TTL or other expiring cache for the simple ruby hashes in the example.  Or use [WeakRef](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html) and handle the possible exception in lookup.